# string manipulating in C?

Tags: c++, arrays, dos, borland-c++

I want to print an array of characters, these characters are underscores first.
Then the user can write characters on these underscores.I used gotoxy() but it doesn't work properly.
That is what i wrote:

```
int main(void)
{
    char arr[20];
    int i;
    char ch;
    clrscr();

    for(i=0;i<=20;i++)
    {
        textattr(0x07);
        cprintf("_");
    } 

    do
    {
        for(i=0;i<=20;i++)
        {
            //gotoxy(i,0);
            //ch = getche();
            if( isprint(ch) == 1)
            {
                arr[i] = ch;
                gotoxy(i,0);
                //printf("%c",ch);
            }
        }
    } while(i == 20);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'll be happy to answer but please clean up the markdown in your question. Four space indent before every line of code.

Comment: What compiler are you using? conio.h isn't well supported (if at all) if you're not using Borland, maybe that's why you can't get it working correctly? Have you tried curses?

Comment: You should tag this question `msdos` or `borlandc` or whatever is relevant to the `clrscr` and `gotoxy` functions, which are not part of C.

Comment: "it doesn't work properly" - please specify what happened that was different from what you expected. E.g. an error, or no output, or output in the wrong place, etc.

Comment: The output must be 20 underscores and the cursor is in the first underscore to write on it, but that is not happening.

Comment: The problem is to put the cursor at the first character of the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing is this: You probably don't want to have all those calls to `gotoxy`, `textattr` and `cprintf` in your main function, since that is not what the main function is supposed to do.

It is much more likely that the main function's purpose is "to read some text from the user, presented nicely in an input field". So you should make this a function:

```
static int
nice_input_field(char *buf, size_t bufsize, int x, int y) {
  int i, ch;

  gotoxy(x, y);
  for (i = 0; i < bufsize - 1; i++) {
    cprintf("_");
  }

  i = 0;
  gotoxy(x, y);
  while ((ch = readkey()) != EOF) {
    switch (ch) {

    case '...': /* ... */
      break;

    case '\b': /* backspace */
      cprintf("_");
      i--;
      gotoxy(x + i, y);
      break;

    case '\t': /* tabulator */
    case '\n': /* enter, return */
      buf[i] = '\0';
      return 0; /* ok */

    default: /* some hopefully printable character */
      if (i == bufsize - 1) {
        cprintf("\a"); /* beep */
      } else {
        buf[i++] = ch;
        gotoxy(x + i, y);
        cprintf("%c", buf[i]);
      }
    }
  }

  /* TODO: null-terminate the buffer */
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Printing an array of characters is fairly easy:

```
char* str = your_array;
while(*str) {
   putc(*str++);
}
```

From memory that should print a string out to the screen.

Comment: Though looking at your code I am not sure that I understand your question properly.

Comment: when i run there must be underscores already printed, number of underscores is the no. of elements in the array.Then the pointer of writing must be at the first underscore and when i write any character, it will be written in that exact position and stored in the array.

Comment: Oh, I see what you want. And you are doing it the wrong way. Curses or Ncurses, as suggested above, would make your life that much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very DOS-specific.  There is not a good general solution to the problem of reading immediate input in a portable way.  It does get asked quite often, so I think the C FAQ broke down and included an answer which you might want to seek out.

That said, I think your bug is that `gotoxy(1, 1)` is the upper corner of the screen, not 0,0.  So you want `gotoxy(i, 1)`